# Binding DataGrid'a к листу или к таблице базы данных на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно связать DataGrid с листом или таблицей базы данных.
Вот так я связываю грид с листом.

```
public List<CopiesOut> _bookList = new List<CopiesOut>();

public List<CopiesOut> BookList      
{
        get { return _bookList; }
        set
        {
            _bookList = value;
            OnPropertyChange("BookList");
        }
}

ItemsSource="{
    Binding Path=BookList, 
    Mode=OneWayToSource, 
    NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
    ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
    BindsDirectlyToSource=True, 
    NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
}"
```

Но при изменение BookList'a по кнопке, грид не меняется.  Пробовал в конструкторе изменять лист, абсолютно ничего на гриде не отображается.

В связи с этим, расскажите как все-таки правильно биндить всякие там листы к датагриду, покидайте хороших статей, туториалов. Заранее очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Мож у вас DataContext пустой?

Comment: Не пустой. 
    ViewModel VM = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = VM;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то...

При `Mode=OneWayToSource` на экране не будет изменений при изменении `Source`.

Вам надо `OneWay` или `TwoWay`.

[BindingMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx).

Comment: Пробовал менять - не помогало. Чтобы  заработало поменял list на ObservableCollection

Comment: Возможно. Я в своих wpf проектах использую кастомный класс, унаследованный от [BindingList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132679.aspx), настолько привык, что на это не смотрю даже...